# Accessing Dataframe value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pycharm

In the code below, what is the best way to loop through the elements under the column "Type" and output the corresponding "Schedule" whenever the "Type" is LEC?

I am using selenium to import scraped data from a website. Then using the pandas library to convert the table into a dataframe

```
   Section Type               Schedule Location
0       A1  LEC    MWF 1:25 pm-2:15 pm  STO B50
1       A1  NaN      R 6:30 pm-8:30 pm     ROOM
2       A2  LEC   MWF 12:20 pm-1:10 pm  STO B50
3       A2  NaN      R 6:30 pm-8:30 pm     ROOM
4       A3  LEC    TR 12:30 pm-1:45 pm  STO B50
5       A3  NaN      R 6:30 pm-8:30 pm     ROOM
6       B1  DIS      T 2:00 pm-3:15 pm  EPC 207
7       B2  DIS      T 3:30 pm-4:45 pm  EPC 207
8       B3  DIS      T 5:00 pm-6:15 pm  EPC 207
9       B4  DIS      R 2:00 pm-3:15 pm  EPC 207
10      B5  DIS      M 2:30 pm-3:45 pm  CAS 324
11      B6  DIS      W 2:30 pm-3:45 pm  CAS 324
12      B7  DIS      R 3:30 pm-4:45 pm  EPC 207
13      SA1  IND   MTWR 1:00 pm-3:00 pm  MCS B29
14      SA2  IND    MTR 6:00 pm-8:30 pm  COM 217
15      SB1  IND  MTWR 11:00 am-1:00 pm  PSY B51
16      SB2  IND    MTR 6:00 pm-8:30 pm  PSY B37
17      A1  LEC  MWF 11:15 am-12:05 pm      STO
18      A1  NaN      R 6:30 pm-8:30 pm      NaN
19      A2  LEC    MWF 2:30 pm-3:20 pm      STO
20      A2  NaN      R 6:30 pm-8:30 pm      NaN
21      A3  LEC     TR 8:00 am-9:15 am      STO
22      A3  NaN      R 6:30 pm-8:30 pm      NaN
23      B1  DIS      M 4:30 pm-5:45 pm      NaN
24      B2  DIS     T 12:30 pm-1:45 pm      NaN
25      B3  DIS      T 3:30 pm-4:45 pm      NaN
26      B4  DIS      W 8:30 am-9:45 am      CAS
27      B5  DIS      W 4:30 pm-5:45 pm      NaN
28      B6  DIS     R 12:30 pm-1:45 pm      NaN
```

Comment: Why? Which purpose would an index like that serve?

Comment: Having duplicate index can have its issues. best way to access rows with specific column values, you should try using the preferred way of `boolean series` e.g. `d[d['Type'] == "DIS"]`

Comment: I would like to classify them. I would ultimately like to access the Schedule data for every type of Class. So for every LEC, it would output it's schedule

Answer (score 0):

I asked a similar question about accessing and storing rows in separate sheets based on criteria in a particular column. You may find the answer Manish Chaudhary gave to my question here helpful:

[Using Openpyxl to create multiple custom spreadsheets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60497136/using-openpyxl-to-create-multiple-custom-spreadsheets)

Ultimately I abandoned using Openpyxl and accomplished the task using pandas as he demonstrates.

Edit:

I came up with a code that creates separate sheets based on class type. This may not be exactly what you asked for but this might be a good place to start:

```
d = pd.read_html("https://www.bu.edu/phpbin/course-search/section/?t=casma124")
d = pd.concat(d)
number_of_rows = 1 #number of rows in dataframe
index_range = list(range(number_of_rows))


d = d.loc[:, ["Section", "Type","Schedule", "Location"]]


print(d)

types = ('LEC','NaN','DIS','IND')

for i in types:
    i = str(i)
    leng = len(i)

    try:
        df = d[d.iloc[:, 1].str[:leng]== i]
    except:
        continue


    df.to_excel(i+'.xlsx', index=False)
    print('Sheet {} saved successfully!'.format(i))
```

Comment: Hey thank you very much for the help ! I have figured out a way to re index my dataframe. I my issue now is more related to accessing a specific index.